# Model Users - Group relationship in CouchDB

Tags: join, couchdb

I have group and user documents that I want to store in CouchDB, user can join multiple groups. One group can have thousands of users. Here are the documents I came up with:

```
Group: { "_id":"group1", "name":"abc", "type":"group" }
Group: { "_id":"group2", "name":"abc", "type":"group" }
User: { "_id":"user1", "login":"whatever", "groupIds": ["group1" , "group2"], "type":"user" }
User: { "_id":"user2", "login":"whatever", "groupIds": ["group2"], "type":"user" }
```

I want to get groups by user id. It seems like the best thing I can do is define this view:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == "user")
  {
    emit(doc._id, doc.groupIds);
  }
}
```

But in this case I need to get group ids in one request and then each group in separate request.
Is there a way to write `groups by user id` view so that all groups were returned in one request to CouchDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the linked documents syntax to get a list of group documents for a given user.  Create this view:

```
function(doc) {
  if( doc.type === 'user' ) {
    var gids = doc.groupIds;
    for( var i=0, l=gids.length; i<l; i++) {
      emit( doc._id, { '_id': gids[i] } );
    }
  }
}
```

And then you will query this with the `include_docs=true` parameter, and Couch sees the special value of `{ "_id": "group1" }` and retrieves that linked document for you.  You will end up with all the group documents in the `doc` element of the returned hash row.